# Central limit theorem Battery

Tags: statistics

The batteries produced in a factory are tested before packing: $1.5\%$ of batteries are found to be faulty, and are scrapped. Whether or not a battery is faulty is independent of whether or not any other battery is faulty.

Experience suggested that a *good* battery will last for $36$ to $45$ hours when used, and that all times within this range are equally likely.

The random variable $D$ is the total time that a box of $100$ good batteries lasts when used. State the distribution of $D$, including the values of any parameters, that may be used to approximate it.

Justify the use of this distribution briefly.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please include the context in which you encountered the problem (homework assignment, reading a book, etc) and what you think the approach to solving this should be, as well as where you are getting stuck, and we will be happy to guide you further.

Comment: It is an assignment. I got stuck in how to find the mean and variance in the above question.

Comment: what is the distribution of each battery's lasting time?

Comment: Can I use binomial distribution for the battery's lasting time? Approximate the distribution by normal distribution, the mean and variance would be, N(np, npq)?

Comment: Note from the problem:

> battery will last for 36 to 45 hours when used, and that all times within this range are equally likely

This does not sound like binomial to me, it is a continuous distribution with equal weight...

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_{100}$ denote the length of time the individual batteries in the pack will last. Then, $X_k$ are independent and identically distributed.

- If you assume all batteries in the pack are good, what is the distribution of each $X_k$?
- Now perhaps some are not good. How does that change the distribution of $X_k$?
- What can you say about approximating the distribution of the average of $X_k$? (Finding mean and variance of $X_k$ will help here.)
- Finally note $D = \sum_{k=1}^{100} X_k$, can you approximate the distribution of $D$ somehow?